# Haxe operator overloading

Tags: operators, operator-overloading, overloading, abstract, haxe

How can I accomplish operator overloading in a way that is convenient to use?

[image]

As you can see, putting an operator overload in a class does nothing. Also, if I use "abstract", I can't even call the Bark() method on Dog. 

Operator overloading shouldn't be so convoluted and unviable.

Comment: I had to take a screenshot of the code, since it kept complaining about my formatting.

Comment: The documentation is pretty clear on this. Operator overloading is for abstracts only and abstracts do not expose underlying fields. If you have an actual question to ask, please do. If you have a concrete suggestion to make, post it on the Haxe issue tracker. Thus far this is just an opinionated rant, posted on one of the few places in the internet that doesn't tolerate them ;)

Comment: my question is pretty clearly how to achieve viable operator overloading.

Answer (score 2):

Operator overloading is only for abstracts at the moment. What you can do is to create and to apply a macro to your context (where your operations are executed) and transform the expression tree so that the operations are mapped to the right methods.

Comment: are you saying I can call a macro by using the operator I need? For example, if I type "new X() + new X()", can I make the '+' operator trigger a macro call to transform the tree?

Comment: You can have the containing method do the trasformation. For example you could add a metadata @:dogOperators on main() and let the macros change the AST.

Answer (score 2):

In haxe 3.1.3, you can add @:forward before the abstract to forward underlying attributes and methods to the abstract.

```
@:forward // add this!
abstract Dog2(Dog) to Dog from Dog
{
    ...
}

new Dog2().Bark(); // no more error!
```

You can also forward specific methods/attributes to the abstract. See [Forwarding abstract fields](http://haxe.org/manual/types-abstract-forward.html)

Comment: How is forwarding like operator overloading?

Comment: It's not. Forwarding is something you can do to abstracts to make the original methods in Dog be available in Dog2. So Dog2 becomes the same as Dog with the added overloaded operators.

Comment: He was looking for a way to make operator overloading convenient. Adding the @:forward solves that problem for now...